# Issue when copying to SnowFlake directly in Azure Data Factory

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

When attempting to copy directly to SnowFlake in Azure Data Factory I get the error

> Direct copying data to Snowflake is only supported when copying from
> Azure Blob Storage or Amazon S3 with DelimitedText, Parquet or JSON
> format, for other scenarios, please enable staging.

Can someone let me know how to enable staging?

[image]

I am updating question with sink settings
[image]

Comment: Hey, Can you please provide the screenshot of the sink settings of copy activity?

Comment: I have updated question with Sink settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the enableStaging setting in the copy activity to specify whether you want the data to be staged in storage before you load it into a destination data store. When you set enableStaging to TRUE, specify the additional properties listed in the following table.

Below MSFT Doc helps :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nandan, I don't see the configuration option to enableStaging. Where is that located

Comment: ok, I located staging, but ADLS Gen 2 not supported. Will have to setup Blob Storage